# How to Convert JSON object colon (:) to equalto (=)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
 var data = [
 { Id: 1,
    key: 'text',
    text: 'Hide',
    language: 'write',
    translation: 'qjjsjqiowqkq' },
  { Id: 1,
    key: 'text',
    text: 'Hide',
    language: 'read',
    translation: 'jejfowffm' },
  { Id: 1,
    key: 'text',
    text: 'Hide',
    language: 'Test',
    translation: 'ijihuhio' }],
```

The code i have written

```
function(data, response) {
var languages       = {};
var zip             = ARCHIVER('zip');


for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    if(languages[obj.language] == undefined || null) {
        languages[obj.language] = {}
    }

    languages[obj.language][obj.key] = obj.translation;
}

Object.keys(languages).forEach((language)=> {
    languages=JSON.stringify(languages[language]);
    languages = languages.replace(/:/g, "=");
  });

zip.pipe(response);
Object.keys(languages).forEach((language)=> {
    zip.append(JSON.stringify(languages[language],null,'\t'), {name : language+".json"});
});

zip.finalize();
}
```

String.replace is not working .

Required output

```
"Hide"="qjjsjqiowqkq";
"Hide"="jejfowffm";
"Hide"="ijihuhio";
```

Iterating and getting data in archive format but not as a required output .
Need to replace (:) to (=) and (,) to (;)
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This might work, try this:

```js
 var data = [
 { Id: 1,
    key: 'text',
    text: 'Hide',
    language: 'write',
    translation: 'qjjsjqiowqkq' },
  { Id: 1,
    key: 'text',
    text: 'Hide',
    language: 'read',
    translation: 'jejfowffm' },
  { Id: 1,
    key: 'text',
    text: 'Hide',
    language: 'Test',
    translation: 'ijihuhio' }]


const fn = (data) => {
  let arr = [];
  data.forEach(d => {
    let str = `${d.text}=${d.translation}`
    arr.push(str);
  })
  return arr;
}


console.log(fn(data).join('\n').toString());
```

Comment: if u see my function if language is diffrent i am making one object and inserting its key and translation like test:{key :translation} read:{key:translation} and if read is coming twice insert its key value in read object .in that case none of the solution works

Comment: need to change in languages variable which contains array of obj.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data.map(item => `${item.text}:${item.translation}`).join("\n")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to replace only "**language**" key then iterate over data object and create a string that contains only **language** key, otherwise you can follow below approach, which converts entire json to string first, then replaces required characters:

Try this:

```
var data = [
    { Id: 1,
        key: 'text',
        text: 'Hide',
        language: 'write',
        translation: 'qjjsjqiowqkq' },
    { Id: 1,
        key: 'text',
        text: 'Hide',
        language: 'read',
        translation: 'jejfowffm' },
    { Id: 1,
        key: 'text',
        text: 'Hide',
        language: 'Test',
        translation: 'ijihuhio' }];

let stringJson  = JSON.stringify(data);
let replacedString = stringJson.replace(":", "="); // Replace ":" symbol by "="
replacedString = stringJson.replace(",", ";"); // Replace "," symbol by ";"

console.log(" res = > \n", replacedString);
```

Output:

```
res = > 
 [{"Id":1;"key":"text","text":"Hide","language":"write","translation":"qjjsjqiowqkq"},{"Id":1,"key":"text","text":"Hide","language":"read","translation":"jejfowffm"},{"Id":1,"key":"text","text":"Hide","language":"Test","translation":"ijihuhio"}]
```

**To get specific answer, you can try something like this :**

```
   let resStr = "";
for(let dataObj of data) {
    resStr+='\"' + dataObj.text + "\"=\"" + dataObj.translation + '\";\n';
}

console.log(resStr);
```

Output:

```
"Hide"="qjjsjqiowqkq";
"Hide"="jejfowffm";
"Hide"="ijihuhio";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(OBJECT_VAL).map(function(val){
var temp = OBJECT_VAL[val];
return `${val}=${temp}`;
});
```

this will return the array of string with '=' signs.